# Can you use Taiko library with Gauge tests written in python?

Tags: getgauge

I am curious if one can use Taiko library for gauge tests written in python? I am trying to write some UI tests for a website. If not, what are the benefit of using gauge tests written python than writing selinium tests?

Regards,
Pawan.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible since Taiko is a JavaScript/TypeScript library